# how to duplicate and modify documents in mongodb using command line

Tags: mongodb, command-line

I am trying to do the following from the command line:

1. search for certain documents within a collection
2. duplicate each found document
3. modify each found document in the same way

Can this be done from the command line?  All I can see are ways to modify documents, which is fine, but I need to duplicate them first.  Is there a script that can find, dup, modify then find next?

Comment: what about _id field?

Comment: @KikoV I'm not sure what you mean.  I'm searching for the needed documents using _id field.  What are you suggesting?

Comment: for dupped documents, what's the _id?

Comment: i honestly don't know.  I know how to dup the documents using rockmongo.  When you hit duplicate, you can change fields.  But, i'm not sure what happens with the document id.

Comment: then, look up my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement a script like this one:

```
var cursor = db.mycollection.find({ **criteria** } );


while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  var x = cursor.next();
  var field1 = x.field1;
  // Perform the changes 
  .
  .
  var field1T = field1.replace(/aaa/g, 'a');
  .
  .
  x.field1 = field1T;

  // this will create a dup
  delete x._id    // I'm not sure if it's delete or unset. I can't test now
  db.mycollection.insert(x);
};
```

and then call it

```
# mongo localhost/mydatabase myscript.js
```

Answer (score 0):

While duplicating a document you have to keep in mind that they have different _id (its like a primary key). You cannot have two documents in a collection having same _id, this has to be unique for each document (*general database concept*).

Now you can easily duplicate like:

suppose you have a document structure like this

```
         {_id:'12345', x:1, y:2}        // assumption
```

now you can do:

1. search for certain document within a collection-->

   ```
   var doc = db.YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.find({_id:'12345'});
   ```
2. duplicate each found document-->

   ```
   doc._id = '54321';         //change the _id
   db.YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.insert(doc); //duplicated
   ```
3. modify each found document in the same way

   if you want to modify duplicated document, do it before inserting it back. in step 2.

Now for many documents, create a file named **dup.js**(suppose), write following in it:

```
    var cur = db.YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.find({QUERY_HERE});
    while(cur.hasNext()){
       var doc = cur.next();
       //change _id of doc to a new value and also do other modifications here
       db.YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.insert(doc);
    }
```

To run the script in the shell do:

```
  mongo localhost:27017/YOUR_DB_NAME dup.js
```

To understand writing a script read:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/